# Is it possible for Encog or Neuroph to run on Android?

Tags: android, neural-network, encog

I am writing an Android app that will be performing image recognition and analysis. I have heard that a neural network is one of the better ways to perform image recognition and have attempted to port the library that Mike O'Neill on CodeProject used in his outstanding handwritten digit recognition application for Win32. However, I recently was told about Encog and Neuroph, two outstanding Java libraries for neural networks/image recognition. I only need the neural network to work, I will be writing my own image recognition suite around another neural network library. Does anyone know if Encog or Neuroph can run on Android, preferably Encog?

**EDIT:** I already Googled this, I'm wondering if anyone can actually attest to the library working.

Comment: @Kaediil do you know if that is usable? What version of Encog is it based on?

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing more then what is there.  I did a quick google search to see what those two tools were and found that link, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that Encog 3.1.0 works on android 4.1.2. For neural networks, I do training on my development machine then dump the net to disk and copy it to the android/project/asset directory.

see org.encog.persist.EncogDirectoryPersistence for serialization.